# BaseAdapter not populating listview

Tags: android, listview, listadapter, baseadapter

So i have a base adapter class that I built.  I also try to use this in one of my activities.  I have a xml for the parent layout and an xml for the rows to inflate.  However, these components are not linking together.  The app doesnt crash but the rows are not inflated (although the parent xml file still displays on the creen).  Could some look at my code and tell me what critical component i am overlooking?  I will only post the relevant code.  Cant post the error logs since no errors are occurring.  Thanks very much

Parent XML (nearby_places_list)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/continuetomap"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/map_continue"
    />

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list_view_nearby"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:divider="#b5b5b5"
       android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector">
   </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Row to Inflate XML (nearby_list_row)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector">"

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/list_selector">
                <TextView
                    android:id= "@+id/name"        
                    android:textSize="20dp" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="name"
                    android:textColor="#54944d"/>
                 <TextView
                    android:id= "@+id/vicinity"        
                    android:textSize="20dp" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="vicinity"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>
                  <TextView
                    android:id= "@+id/openorclosed"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Open"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>    
                    </LinearLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.74" >

                 <Button
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/button_add_to_fav"
                android:background="@drawable/add_square"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                />

               <Button
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/button_call_rest"
                android:background="@drawable/add_square"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button_add_to_fav"
                />

            </RelativeLayout>

          </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Base Adapter Class

```
public class AdapterForList extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> alHm;
    private final String TAG_A;
    private final String TAG_B;
    private final String TAG_C;


    public AdapterForList(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> alhm, String TAG_1, String TAG_2, String TAG_3) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.alHm = alhm;
        TAG_A = TAG_1;
        TAG_B = TAG_2;
        TAG_C = TAG_3;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView , ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.nearby_list_row, parent, false);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vicinity);
        TextView tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.openorclosed);
        Button btnAdd= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_add_to_fav);
        Button btnCall= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_call_rest);

        if (alHm.get(position).containsKey(TAG_A)){  // get the value from the key (if it exist) and set the first text view to it 
            String value = alHm.get(position).get(TAG_A);
            tv1.setText(value);;
        }

        if (alHm.get(position).containsKey(TAG_B)){   
            String value = alHm.get(position).get(TAG_B);
            tv2.setText(value);;
        }

        if (alHm.get(position).containsKey(TAG_C)){  // get the value from the key (if it exist) and set the first text view to it 
            String value = alHm.get(position).get(TAG_C);
            tv3.setText(value);;
        }

        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return alHm.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

}
```

Relevant activity code

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
    if (result){
        // adding data to listview
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_nearby);
        lv.setAdapter(new AdapterForList(context, listOfHM, JSONextractor.TAG_NAME,   
            JSONextractor.TAG_VICINITY,  JSONextractor.TAG_OPERATINGHOURS_OPENNOW));

        //more code ...

    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried in the AdapterForList constructor logging the size of the alhm arrayList? becouse if is empty thats the problem...

Comment: alhm has the correct count of 20 and the values in it are correct. the correct listview is also being found

Comment: WTF?!?! it works fine now. i havent changed a single line of code. i have run this and stepped through this in the debugger multiple times

Comment: Does anyone know why a program would run differently when i havent changed any code? this does use async task so does that have somthing to do with it?

Comment: If you are obtaining data from a server maybe the server sends different data ...

Comment: I am getting my data using googleplaces api.  but that server was up because i was able to view the locations on a map...

Comment: One last question, I'm not 100% sure why its statement to use the following if statement.

if (convertView == null){ // assign widgets}

Comment: is for performance, see this link: http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out my code did work (but not optimally).  I posted below how to correctly use the base adapter

Just read the article (really opened my mind) posed by savadow. basically the way i have my BaseAdapter im not utilizing any of the optimization ability of the class.  Instead I will change the code to the following in the base adapter class.

http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView , ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null){  
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.nearby_list_row, parent, false);
        }
        // now if the convertView is not null i simply update the values rather than re-inflate the view (inflating is expensive)

        tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vicinity);
        tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.openorclosed);
        btnAdd= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_add_to_fav);
        btnCall= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_call_rest);
```